# Quiero saber ¿por que me sale un símbolo extraño al cargar una un vector tipo char? en lenguaje C

Tags: c

Mi código es este, esta en lenguaje C, y lo aplicado es lo que me enseñaron en la universidad.
Estamos dando vectores y matrices, no es que me cueste pero errores así no se como solucionar, el codigo es simple pero me llevo tiempo que la visualización quede así.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void){
    
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    
    char comida[7][40]={"Turrónes", "Garrapiñ","Budines ","P Dulce ", "Sidras  ", "Ananá   ","Promos  "};
    int N;
    int colum=6;
    
    printf("==============================================================================================\n");
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de Promos: ");
    scanf("%i", &N);
    
    int matriz[N][7];
    int i,j,k;
    char aux[20];
    char promo[N][20];
    
    
        
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        
        strcat(promo[i], "PROMO");
        strcat(promo[i], "-");
        k=i+1;
        itoa(k,aux,10);
        strcat(promo[i],aux);
        
        for(j=0;j<colum;j++){
            printf("Ingrese la cantidad de %s que compro la Promo %i",comida[j], i+1);
            printf("\t");
            scanf("%i", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    //Visualizaion
    
    for(i=0; i<7; i++){
        printf("|   %s   |", comida[i]); //\t para tabular (dejar 8 espacios)
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<colum;j++){
            //printf("\t"); 
            //printf("%i \t",matriz[i][j]);
            printf("|      %i       |", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        
        printf("|   %s    |", promo[i]);
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

En la primera parte del codigo creo un vector y una matriz y pido al usuario que lo cargue con los datos.
Y la otra parte es la visualizacion, no noto que este nada mal en el codigo.
y lo que me imprime es esto

```
|   Turrónes   ||   Garrapiñ   ||   Budines    ||   P Dulce    ||   Sidras     ||   Ananá      ||   Promos     |
|      1       ||      2       ||      3       ||      4       ||      5       ||      6       ||   PROMO-1    |
|      1       ||      2       ||      3       ||      4       ||      5       ||      6       ||   PROMO-2    |
```

El simbolo raro en el primer PROMO-1 No se porque me sale, y lo quiero solucionar.

Soy nuevo en esto y este es mi primer lenguaje, es un trabajo del la universidad.

[image: Error de visualizacion]